# Google Cloud Messaging Notifications on users multiple devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I watched the video from Google I/O about GCM, at the end of the video lecturer shows the example how notifications works on multiple devices of the same user. He dismissed the notification and it disappeared on all devices.
I have searched how can I implement the same feature, but unfortunately didn't find any examples of documentation.
Maybe someone can help with simple example or documentation reference(if I have missed it).
Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications)** is what you are looking for.